# How to delete a breakpoint from multiple breakpoint list in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

I've set a breakpoint on some file:line, and since there are multiple such files, this caused GDB to create multiple breakpoints.

```
(gdb) b drv.c:2145
Breakpoint 1 at 0xa8b8172: drv.c:2145. (3 locations)


(gdb) info b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE>
1.1                         y     0x0a8b8172 in soc_property_ci_get_str at /lspace/seb/broadcom/src/soc/common/drv.c:2145
1.2                         y     0x0a8b81d8 in soc_property_ci_get_str at /lspace/seb/broadcom/src/soc/common/drv.c:2145
1.3                         y     0x0aaa364d in soc_dpp_info_config_common_tm at /lspace/seb/broadcom/src/soc/dpp/drv.c:2145
```

Is there a way to delete breakpoints from multiple breakpoint list?
When trying to delete the breakpoint using it's index, it fails with an error.

```
(gdb) d 1.1
warning: bad breakpoint number at or near '1.1'
```

Comment: @H.S. This clears all breakpoints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to delete breakpoints from multiple breakpoint list?

No, but you can disable individual breakpoint location in a breakpoint with multiple locations with `disable` command:

```
(gdb) disable 1.1
```

See [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html):

> You cannot delete the individual locations from a breakpoint. However,
>   each location can be individually enabled or disabled by passing
>   breakpoint-number.location-number as argument to the enable and
>   disable commands. It’s also possible to enable and disable a range of
>   location-number locations using a breakpoint-number and two
>   location-numbers, in increasing order, separated by a hyphen, like
>   breakpoint-number.location-number1-location-number2, in which case GDB
>   acts on all the locations in the range (inclusive). Disabling or
>   enabling the parent breakpoint (see Disabling) affects all of the
>   locations that belong to that breakpoint.